# Making a call to a Flask Restful API with invoke-restmethod and JWT auth

Tags: powershell, rest, api, flask

I have this API that I made with Flask (Python) and I am unable to get powershell to successfully make an API request to it. The problem is not the API because I tested it with postman and everything works as it should. More precisely it's when I add JWT token auth that it's not working with powershell, in my api the Create, Update and delete functions are protected with JWT token auth and the basic Read function have no auth at all. Below is the powershell code i am using:

Here is the function that generate my token (that part is working, note that I removed username and password from the function for security purposes):

```
function get-token {
param (
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$user,
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$password
)
$body = @{
    username="$user"
    password="$password"
}
$jsonbody = $body | ConvertTo-Json
$uri = "https://codegenius.live/api/auth"
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Accept","application/json")
$headers.Add("Content-Type","application/json")
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $jsonbody -Headers $headers
$response.access_token
}
```

This function will generate a token like this:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1ODIyMzA2OTUsImlhdCI6MTU4MjIzMDM5NSwibmJmIjoxNTgyMjMwMzk1LCJpZGVudGl0eSI6MX0.8wZZJEGxV7P4ZzN23eZ3d5-MGJ00N5zKHuCZXn9XRuw
```

Here is the call i am trying to make that doesn't work:

```
$body = @{
tpl_name="my template name"
tpl_subject="my template subject"
tpl_plaintext_content="bla bla bla"
tpl_html_content="bla bla bla"
} 

$authheader = "JWT " + (get-token)
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Accept","application/json")
$headers.Add("Content-Type","application/json")
$headers.Add("Authorization",$authheader)
$jsonbody = $body | ConvertTo-Json
$uri = "https://codegenius.live/api/add-email"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $jsonbody -Headers $headers
```

The request response message is this one:

```
Invoke-RestMethod :
500 Internal Server Error
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server         
is overloaded or
there is an error in the application.
Au caractère Ligne:25 : 17
+ ... $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $jsonbody  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-    
RestMethod], WebEx
ception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

This is very strange because as I said it is working with Postman (see below images), I have tried googling the issue but I found no clue on how to actually solve this.
EDIT: the images show that in postman i used http instead of https, this is not the issue. In powershell http or https nothing works!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your line to this,

```
$authheader = "JWT $(get-token)"
```